# Fat-Free Framework redirects to invalid url

Tags: php, redirect, fat-free-framework

I'm currently using Fat-Free Framework for a project. But whenever I browse to **http://localhost/fatfree/admin/login/**, F3 will redirect to the url without slash ("/") at the end. I know this is normal, but the url that I'm being redirected to is invalid. F3 redirects me to **http://localhosthttp//localhost/fatfree//admin/index** (exact url)

I'm running PHP 7.1.0 + Apache 2.4 on Windows 7 64 bit

**Config/config.ini.php:**

```
[globals]
DEBUG=3
UI=Views/
BASE=http://localhost/fatfree/
SITENAME="my website"

[configs]
Config/database.ini.php=false
Config/routes.ini.php=false
```

**Config/routes.ini.php:**

```
;<?php die; ?>

[routes]

; main section
GET /=Controllers\Main->index
GET /products=Controllers\Products

; customer section

; admin section
GET /admin=Controllers\Admin->index
GET /admin/index=Controllers\Admin->index
GET /admin/login=Controllers\Admin->login
```

How do I make sure that F3 redirects to the correct url?

Do I have to set a Framework Variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to set `BASE` in your config. F3 will find it on its own.